# Camel-Kafka java.io.EOFException - NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, activemq-classic, kerberos

I am trying to produce messages to Kafka (Cloudera) from an ActiveMQ-Camel bridge using **Kerberos**.

- **ActiveMQ** v5.15.4
- **Camel**: 2.21.1
- **Kafka Clients**:1.1.0
- **Server version**: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

The camel.xml snipet is:

```
<log message="Started The Producer Route" />
<to uri="kafka://10.100.70.00:9092?topic=MyEvents.s1.v1&amp;brokers=10.100.70.00:9092&amp;requestTimeoutMs=305000&amp;retries=3&amp;keySerializerClass=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer&amp;saslMechanism=GSSAPI&amp;serializerClass=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer&amp;securityProtocol=PLAINTEXT&amp;saslKerberosServiceName=kafka"/>
```

This is the kafka client config from log:

```
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [10.148.70.74:9092]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.id =
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = []
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
linger.ms = 0
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 305000
retries = 3
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = kafka
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT (**SASL_PLAINTEXT not supported**)
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

Log level: DEBUG

Jaas file:

```
KafkaClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    keyTab="./user.keytab"
    useTicketCache=false
    serviceName="kafka"
    principal=" Group/user@DOMAIN.LAN";
};
```

Export:

```
KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/activemq/conf/Jaas.conf"
```

When I send a message I receive the following log at **DEBUG** level and the message is not delivered:

```
    java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:124)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:235)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:196)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:557)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:495)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_171
```

At **INFO** level I only see this in the log:

```
WARN  | [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker 10.100.70.00:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected | org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient | kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1
```

Why am I getting this error? Please help!

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by not authorised user to produce messages to Kafka.

Such problem can be mitigated by verifying the keytab file as a prerequisite:

- Verify service account name from keytab file: `klist -k -t <keytabFile>`
- Authenticate to Active Directory: `kinit -k -t <keytabFile> <servicePrincipal>`

There shall not be any errors.